# Parse DateTime issue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, format

How to parse following date-time string in c# DateTime object which is received from WebSphere in Linux environment.

```
string serverDate = "Sat Nov 03 13:03:13 GMT+05:30 2012"
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this format "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"

Comment: Considering "GMT" is not part of any time format, perhaps you should look at the duplicate again.

Comment: Thanks all, wudzik's possible duplicate works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string serverDate = "Sat Nov 03 13:03:13 GMT+05:30 2012";

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(serverDate, @"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \G\M\TK yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note how I had to escape each of the "GMT" characters separately.

Comment: I think `@"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \G\M\TK yyyy"` would make it easier to read and understand.

Comment: @Herdo True, I'll amend it.